# How to create SQL server2005 database on remote machine using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I am creating a desktop application, in which I have to log in into SQL Server 2005 on the remote machine and have to create a database, User etc.  By using jTDS I am able to create a connection to the database as well as able to execute "SELECT" commnads but not able to execute database commands like- create database, create user etc.

Here is my test code:

```
public class Test {

// JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.96.11.31:1433;useNTLMv2=true;domain=myDomain";
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{
          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

          //STEP 4: Execute a query
          System.out.println("Creating database...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();

          String sql = "CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS";
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
          System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
       }catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing we can do
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }//end finally try
       }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
    }//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: As long as the login you are using has the appropriate permissions you should be able to do this in the same way, for example with the exeute() method of a Statement. Please paste the code you are using to execute and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create a DB via JDBC then the you'll need a user with permissions to connect to the *master* database on that server.  Create a java.sql.Connection object to the *master* database then simply create the Statement and execute the SQL:
"CREATE DATABASE MyDB"

I'm a little confused by the question, so I apologize if I misinterpreted it.

Comment: thanks for your interest. the error i am getting is "java.sql.SQLException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. "

Comment: @vermap: Then Johnny is right.  The account you're using to connect with the database doesn't have permission to create new databases.